# Heroku - Can't find maven child module pom

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I am having some trouble pushing a multi-module maven project to Heroku (it worked okay as a single pom in the past).

I can build it find locally however on Heroku I get:

```
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done
-----> Executing: mvn -B -DskipTests=true clean install
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR]   
       [ERROR]   The project web-backend:0.3.3-SNAPSHOT (/tmp/build_f3314e49682a8616ea1531b46a5c5985/pom.xml) has 2 errors
   [ERROR]     Child module /tmp/build_f3314e49682a8616ea1531b46a5c5985/web of /tmp/build_f3314e49682a8616ea1531b46a5c5985/pom.xml does not exist
   [ERROR]     Child module /tmp/build_f3314e49682a8616ea1531b46a5c5985/web-task of /tmp/build_f3314e49682a8616ea1531b46a5c5985/pom.xml does not exist
```

Those pom.xml do exist though, I my structure is like this:

```
main-project
--pom.xml (parent)
--web
----pom.xml
--web-task
----pom.xml
```

As I said building it locally works fine, it's heroku.

My main parent pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"           xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>web-task</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <heroku.plugin.version>0.3.4</heroku.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In each submodule I reference the parent as well. I can post those too if required but I think those aren't a problem yet as it is not even being read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that all of your `pom.xml` files are checked into Git, and also check the case of the directory names matche the case in the strings values of the `<module>` element (on Heroku it will be case sensitive, but it may not be on your local platform).

Comment: Your on to something! I just did a git ls-files and my git repo is tracking the files but on a different case name, so that is 'Web/pom.xml' rather than 'web/pom.xml' but my directory is called 'web'.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, check upper/lower cases.